# What version of angular to use in a new project?

Tags: angular, version

I need to start a project with angular in the company where I work. Currently, most projects are developed using version 4 but I have the chance to choose the version.

What do you recommend? I want to know the reasons for using and not using a specific version.

Thanks!

Comment: It is recommended that you start any new Angular project with the most recent version, which is currently v6. That way your project is up to date with all performance improvements and bug fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you always use the latest version which you can find by following [this](https://angular.io/docs) URL. As I think the main reason why you should choose latest one is that there are many improvements, speed optimizations and bug fixes. So why choose old version when you always can be up to date!

Answer (score 0):

According to me you can choose the more stable version of any platform instead of choosing the latest version of it , because some of the features may be in preview state which is not reliable. So in your case going with Angular 4 or 5 would be good.

Refer this link for more details on [angular versions](https://angular.io/guide/releases/)

For new features in angular 6 refer [this link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/angular-what-is-the-new-briefly-e6837348dd3a)